# Is 'Could you please looking into the issue?' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, business-language

I have seen a question as in the title above in a formal thread. Is it grammatically correct using *looking* here?

And also what about these alternatives?

- Can you please look into the issue?
- Could you please examine the issue?

Which one of those is more polite and also formal?

Comment: The second one is certainly more formal.

Comment: Following (can could shall should will would may might must) always use the infinitive form or the verb:  *can look*, but not *can looking*,  *can looked*, *can looks*.

Comment: *Is 'Could you please looking into the issue?'  grammatically correct?* No, it is not.

Comment: @Greybeard - Technically, 'Could you please looking into the issue?' is at least informally correct, if the context was "You can please the CEO by doing X, Y, or Z.  Could you please [the CEO by] looking into this issue?  Maybe."

Comment: @HotLicks No. *Please* in your suggestion requires an explicit direct object, or at least imply it with *by*. "Could you please *verb*" means "Please would you *verb*", and the present participle for *verb* is wrong: it needs to be the infinitive as GEdgar commented.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - You're thinking of the wrong definition of "please".

Comment: No, I'm not. Your use of *please* **requires** a direct object (which may be implied with the use of *by*). If you don't have a direct object who is to be pleased, it's wrong.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - If you please.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is NO. "Could you please looking into the issue" is not grammatically correct. If you are making a request to someone to do something in the future, the correct way to form an imperative is to use the regular verb stem without attaching any tense to it:

"Will you please *pass* the salt?" or

"Will you please *sit* still?"

There are some requests that could be made using a participle:

"Would you mind *running* to the store?" 
Note that though English speakers may use this to make a request, they are really asking if the person would mind performing the activity, which is not the same as an imperative.

For your specific case: In the first place, I would use "Will you" instead of "Can you" or "Could you." It is generally better to use "will" when making polite requests. "Can" refers to ability, whereas "Will" refers to the person's own willingness to perform your request.

Either "Will you please look into the issue", or "Will you please examine the issue" would be fine.